# Xcode Swift Pausing And Resuming Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I am making a game using Xcode Swift SpriteKit where a character is running, and then when the character is told to jump, it moves up and stops animating, and resumes animating when it hits the ground.  I have the following code but I am not sure what to do to rerun the animation.

Here is my code for starting the animation:

```
var BigLeftTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ninja Pro 1")
var BigLeftTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ninja Pro 2")
var BigLeftTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ninja Pro 3")
var BigLeftTexture4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ninja Pro 4")
var BigLeftTexture5 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ninja Pro 5")
var BigLeftTexture6 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ninja Pro 6")
BigPerson = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ninja Pro 4")

var leftanimation1 = SKAction.animateWithTextures([BigLeftTexture1, BigLeftTexture2, BigLeftTexture3, BigLeftTexture4, BigLeftTexture5, BigLeftTexture6], timePerFrame: 0.065)
var LeftSideRunning = SKAction.repeatActionForever(leftanimation1)
BigPerson.runAction(LeftSideRunning, withKey: "BigStopLeftSide")
```

Here is my code for stopping the animation:

BigPerson.removeActionForKey("BigStopLeftSide")

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are experiencing

Comment: I am trying to pause the animation and resume it when it is done moving, however it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// to stop the action
BigPerson.paused = true

// to move on
BigPerson.paused = false
```

Comment: If the goal is to pause a certain action, then you don't need to pause the whole node. You can just pause that action.

Comment: Hi Whirlwind, how would you do that? With `.Speed = 0`?